# how to debug python function which is part of vim plugin?

Tags: python, debugging, vim, vim-plugin

The python invocation is defined in some of my .vim files.

`:breakadd file linenumber xx.vim` doesn't seem to work.

When I press a key that triggers the invocation of certain python functions, it doesn't stop at that line. What happened?
By the way, I am in vim's debug mode since I opened the file using `vim -D filename`.

As shown by the following picture, what I want to do is debug a python function which is invoked when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in vim.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some simple check and I see that rpdb2 works when invoked from vim. So you can use it (with GUI frontend called winpdb or with console tool called also rpdb2).

http://winpdb.org/